# shared_ptr use_count event once a certain value is reached

Tags: c++, memory-management, shared-ptr

For better performance in memory management (new resp. malloc takes very much time in my application) I want to reuse objects wrapped by shared_ptr.

I know that the objects have to be deleted as soon as use_count() reaches a certain value. Currently when use_count() equals that value I remove the objects from their containers that they are deleted and create new objects when needed.

Is there a way to get an event (function, lambda expression, whatever) as soon as use_count() reaches a certain value?
If there would be a way, I could write the objects in a list to be reused instead of deletion.

edit: My idea is as follows - written down quickly.

```
class MyClass {
public:
  MyClass() {};
  virtual ~MyClass() {}
  atomic<shared_ptr<MyClass>> next;
};

// allocate memory quickly in one block
vector<shared_ptr<MyClass>> memory;
memory.reserve(SIZE);
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i) memory.emplace_back(make_shared<MyClass>());

atomic<shared_ptr<MyClass>> pool = memory[0];
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < SIZE - 1; ++i) memory[i]->next = memory[i+1];

// object "creation"
shared_ptr<MyClass> create() {
  // here everything should be atomically done
  shared_ptr<MyClass> c = pool;
  pool = c->next;
  return c;
}

// object ready for reuse
void deletion_if_use_count_is_1(shared_ptr<MyClass> d) {
  // here everything should be atomically done
  d->next = pool;
  pool = d;
}
```

Perhaps there's a better way to achieve this?
But as you can see, use_count() will never be 0, but I want to reuse the objects; the shared_ptr don't need to be touched.

Comment: The only significant value of `use_count` is 0. And you can detect when that happens because the pointed object's destructor will be executed.

Comment: Generally I wouldn't recommend re-using shared_ptr's, and I don't think they're setup to be re-initialized (which isn't to say it's not possible). It also sounds like you should be using weak pointers, that way you don't have to remove them from your container when their reference count reaches 1 (you would eventually have to take care of them when they become invalid, but the memory can at least be freed in the meantime).

Comment: `shared_ptr` doesn't provide any sort of notification mechanism.  Are you sure `shared_ptr` or even dynamic allocation is really what you need in your application?

Comment: I don't quite understand the part with "deleted as soon as use_count() reaches a certain value" - objects owned by shared_ptr should only be deleted when use_count == 0; And that you can easily detect by providing a custom deleter, then based on some conditions you can decide to delete the object or not. Another question is how do you plan to reuse it.

Comment: Thanks for your replies! I edited my post and added a bit code. I hope it's better understandable what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a custom deleter for your shared_ptr that actually does not delete the underlying object but inserts its pointer into a list of reusable objects.

You can't specify deleters with `make_shared` so you will have to write your own, eg:

```
std::shared_ptr<ExpensiveType> make_shared_ExpensiveType(ExpensiveType* expensiveType)
{
    return std::shared_ptr<ExpensiveType>(expensiveType, deleterFunc);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added some code. I think my use_count never gets to 0 and standard deleter is never called - except when the program ends.

Comment: It won't reach zero as long as you keep the shared_ptr in the list.  It sounds like what you really want is a list of weak_ptr, not shared_ptr

Comment: I think you are right, thanks. It should be a vector of weak_ptr and a "removed" deleter. - I have to think about it a bit.